# Trouble combining THREE SELECT statements, UNION not working

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, union

I have huge trouble combining the three select statements, i have tried union it does not work, as separate select statements they do work however i need the rest to be one swift statement, if possible even putting the final records in a random order

```
      SELECT DISTINCT email 
      FROM customer_1_tbl
      WHERE email NOT IN (SELECT temp.email 
                          FROM temp_emails AS temp) 
        AND substring_index(email, '@', -1) = 'seznam.cz'
      ORDER BY RAND() 
      LIMIT 6

      UNION

      SELECT DISTINCT email 
      FROM customer_1_tbl
      WHERE email  NOT IN (SELECT temp.email 
                           FROM temp_emails AS temp)    
        AND substring_index(email, '@', -1) = 'gmail.com'
      ORDER BY RAND() 
      LIMIT 6

      UNION 

      SELECT DISTINCT email 
      FROM customer_1_tbl
      WHERE email NOT IN (SELECT temp.email 
                          FROM temp_emails AS temp) 
        AND substring_index(email, '@', -1) != 'gmail.com'
        AND substring_index(email, '@', -1) != 'seznam.cz'
        AND RAND() < (SELECT ((6/COUNT(*))*10) 
                      FROM customer_1_tbl)
      ORDER BY RAND() 
      LIMIT 6
```

Comment: Put ORDER BY in the end of your query.

Comment: the issue I have then is the actual records for the first two selects will always be the same. so I need to get random six each time

Comment: What does not work with the union?

Comment: In my script it does not run it returns the boolean value false. If I remove the order by rand() it works however I need the 6 records from the select to be random

Comment: Can't you combine everything into a single query - ORing the final part of the WHERE clause & get 6 random values from the single query as you are doing now.

Comment: Do you always expect exactly 18 rows? Do UNION ALL in that case, to keep duplicated e-mail addresses (from the different SELECT's).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need the ORDER BY in every query, then try this :

```
SELECT * FROM(
    SELECT DISTINCT email 
    FROM customer_1_tbl
    WHERE email NOT IN (SELECT temp.email 
                                        FROM temp_emails AS temp) 
    AND substring_index(email, '@', -1) = 'seznam.cz'
    ORDER BY RAND() 
    LIMIT 6
) AS A

UNION

SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT email 
    FROM customer_1_tbl
    WHERE email  NOT IN (SELECT temp.email 
                                         FROM temp_emails AS temp)    
    AND substring_index(email, '@', -1) = 'gmail.com'
    ORDER BY RAND() 
    LIMIT 6
) AS B

UNION 
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT email 
    FROM customer_1_tbl
    WHERE email NOT IN (SELECT temp.email 
                                        FROM temp_emails AS temp) 
    AND substring_index(email, '@', -1) != 'gmail.com'
    AND substring_index(email, '@', -1) != 'seznam.cz'
    AND RAND() < (SELECT ((6/COUNT(*))*10) 
                                FROM customer_1_tbl)
    ORDER BY RAND() 
    LIMIT 6
) AS C
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to use ORDER BY clauses on the partial queries rather than on the whole, use parentheses:

```
(
 SELECT DISTINCT email 
  FROM customer_1_tbl
  WHERE email NOT IN (SELECT temp.email 
                      FROM temp_emails AS temp) 
    AND substring_index(email, '@', -1) = 'seznam.cz'
  ORDER BY RAND() 
  LIMIT 6
)
  UNION
(
  SELECT DISTINCT email 
  FROM customer_1_tbl
  WHERE email  NOT IN (SELECT temp.email 
                       FROM temp_emails AS temp)    
    AND substring_index(email, '@', -1) = 'gmail.com'
  ORDER BY RAND() 
  LIMIT 6
)
  UNION 
(
  SELECT DISTINCT email 
  FROM customer_1_tbl
  WHERE email NOT IN (SELECT temp.email 
                      FROM temp_emails AS temp) 
    AND substring_index(email, '@', -1) != 'gmail.com'
    AND substring_index(email, '@', -1) != 'seznam.cz'
    AND RAND() < (SELECT ((6/COUNT(*))*10) 
                  FROM customer_1_tbl)
  ORDER BY RAND() 
  LIMIT 6
)
```

Comment: Use `parentheses` isn't enough.

Comment: thanks that does work, Do you mind explaining whz what you did works I can see what you added however I am a beginner and i want a firmer grasp on why yours works lol

Comment: As mentioned, I only added the parentheses to your query. Without them you cannot use ORDER BY (and LIMIT) per partial query; there could be only one ORDER BY (and LIMIT) for the whole query then, which is not what you want.

Comment: BTW: As the emails retrieved with the three partial queries are different because of the different `WHERE` clauses, there is no sense in having the DBMS look out for duplicates, which is what `UNION` does. Use `UNION ALL` instead, so as to spare the dbms the additional work.